# Windows advanced options menu keeps appearing

Tags: windows, boot

I just get the Windows advanced options menu when I boot my computer. When I choose "start Windows normally", the boot screen appears and goes directly to Windows advanced options menu again.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you able to pick "safe mode" to at least boot into that repair mode? Also, list which version of windows you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Run `msconfig` and check if *Normal startup* is selected in the *General* tab:

[image: MSConfig - 7]